# How do I report a questionable review?

Tags: support, review, reporting

I sometimes run into an edit being rejected on grounds (/ with comments) that make me suspect that the reviewer was <strike>not paying attention</strike> making a mistake. Is there a way to report the review decision for moderation?

I spend over 30 minutes trying to make a quality edit that would benefit future readers of some answer. In this case it turns out the reviewer rejects 245 out of 682 reviews and reviewed my edit along with 19 others within 7 minutes (average of 21 seconds per edit: reading, weighing, write comment on reasoning).

Waiting hours for a review is not nice, but understandable. When this waiting is for nothing because of hasty reviewing it is a waste of both my time and the other reviewer that already reviewed and accepted the edit.

**This is all assuming that the edit was quality and the review was not. I believe so, but how to arbitrage such a case? This is the subject for this question.**

I am writing this while having no reviewing experience myself yet, so it seems easy to judge what I might not fully understand. I do assume the best intentions of our reviewers.

Nevertheless mistakes can be made and it is important that reviewers have a way to receive feedback in case of bad calls. I think this is an important subject for (in this case) Stack Overflow because one or more of such encounters can demotivate me (/ users in general) to make honest attempts to improve the content available to this community.

Searching Meta for this subject revealed a lot of hits about review-audits. This post is (as I understand it) not about review audits, but about flagging review decisions. I do understand that nobody likes his/her edit being rejected, which could result in a lot of emotional flags on correct rejects.

I do have ideas on how Stack Exchange can deal with this, but **with this topic I would specifically like to gauge if the Stack Exchange community recognizes this as a problem and if Stack Exchange already has concrete plans / features / intentions for dealing with this**. Depending on the responses we can start a concrete question weighting solutions.

Comment: Answer is the last sentence in dupe's answer: "If you come across a legitimate case of review abuse (e.g. a user that is rejecting everything it reviews with the same rejection reason), pick one post that the user reviewed, and flag it for moderator attention. Use the 'other' option and explain in the post what you found."

Comment: As for your case, I didn't find any rejected edit of yours. You mean [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21804260)? It's still pending. Edit: approved, but it's really not trivial, hit me up on chat for more details. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thank you for you quick response and link to similar question. It is indeed about the edit you link, but I try not to make this question / topic about that specific edit. At least now I learned about a way to flag a review decision, but it was (apparently) not obvious to me. A flag button in the context of the review would also make it easier to clarify what exactly was being flagged. Anyway. Back on topic: do you recognize it might be worthwhile to improve something here?

Comment: More concretely: the reviewer that rejected get's no feedback out of this. Apparently you do consider that specific edit appropriate (thanks for the approve) :-)

Comment: TL;DR It's appropriate but not really needed. I'll usually skip such reviews since they require lots of time to think over, and I can understand those who reject. They don't abuse their review powers.

Comment: You could avoid inline links (use the other kind of links instead). This makes it easier for the reviewers and increases the likelihood the suggested edit will be accepted.